# I cant Upload SWF Files With PHP

Tags: php, file, input, flash

I have 2 input file in 1 form. When I'm trying to post with a image `print_r` or `var_dump` showing its properties.

But when I try to post with an swf `print_r` or `var_dump` saying empty and can't post.

So how can I upload swf files ? Thanks.

```
echo var_dump($_FILES);

if($_FILES["oyun_yolu_file"]["type"] == "application/x-shockwave-flash")
{
    echo "aha";
    echo var_dump($_FILES["oyun_yolu_file"]);
}
```

I have uploaded code already but my problem is I can't upload swf files, I can upload regular files like txt, image etc.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Resim Yolu</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="resim_yolu" class="resim_yolu" style="width:260px !important" />
<span id="kirmizi" style="padding:0px 10px">yada</span>
<input type="file" name="resim_yolu_file" class="resim_yolu_file" />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Oyun Yolu</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="oyun_yolu" class="oyun_yolu" style="width:260px !important" />
<span id="kirmizi" style="padding:0px 10px">yada</span>
<input type="file" name="oyun_yolu_file" class="oyun_yolu_file" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: what did you tried so far? show the code.

Comment: @QaisarSatti im waiting ur comment

Comment: need  form html code too

Comment: @QaisarSatti im added

Comment: i test this code myself and fine no problem with that just adding the submit button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tested this code by myself and it is working

```
<?php
//echo var_dump($_FILES);
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
if($_FILES["oyun_yolu_file"]["type"] == "application/x-shockwave-flash")
{
    echo "aha";
    echo var_dump($_FILES["oyun_yolu_file"]);
}}
 ?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Oyun Yolu</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="oyun_yolu" class="oyun_yolu" style="width:260px !important" />
<span id="kirmizi" style="padding:0px 10px">yada</span>
<input type="file" name="oyun_yolu_file" class="oyun_yolu_file" />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Oyun Açıklaması</td>
<td>
<textarea cols="45" rows="5" name="oyun_aciklama" style="width:264px !important; padding:4px;"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="submit" name="add">
</td></tr></table>
</form>
```

the output was check your file

**ahaarray(5) { ["name"]=> string(23) "Car-speakers-590x90.swf" ["type"]=> string(29) "application/x-shockwave-flash" ["tmp_name"]=> string(23) "E:\xamp\tmp\php7D0E.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(116887) }**

Comment: Thank u @Qaisar Satti swf file working on Flash Player Projector but i dont know why not working in input file :D Maybe they are protecting swf file.. Anyway i tested another swf file and worked silly me :)